# Where to get the most up to date Android Support Package

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

**My Question:** Where can I get the `android-support-v4.jar`?

**What I have tried:** I went to [Android.com's documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) on getting the package and it states:

The Support Package is provided as a downloadable package from the Android SDK Manager. To install:

```
Launch the Android SDK Manager.
From Eclipse, you can select Window > Android SDK Manager. Or, launch SDK Manager.exe from the <sdk>/ directory (on Windows only) or android from the <sdk>/tools/ directory.
Expand the Android Repository, check Android Support package and click Install selected.
Proceed to install the package.
When done, all files (including source code, samples, and the .jar files) are saved into the <sdk>/extras/android/support/ directory. This directory contains each of the different support libraries, such as the library for API level 4 and up and the library for API level 13 and up, each named with the respective version (such as v4/).
```

However I don't see the Android Support Package in my listing. How can I fix this, or is their documentation wrong?

[image: What I see]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be found in the **Google Inc.** repository within the **Repository** sorting.
When sorting by **API level** you can find it in the **Extras** folder.

In both cases the package you're looking for is named **Android Support Library**.

Comment: Thanks! So what you're saying is the documentation is wrong when it says: `Expand the Android Repository, check Android Support package`... It should say: `Expand the Google Inc Repository, check Android Support package`...